# How to assign (automatically if possible) unique, SHORT id numbers when adding instances of a class, C# Repo Design Pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, uniqueidentifier

I'm very new to even the basics of C#, so finding my answer among so many complex (to me) related questions is proving to be a challenge.

Basically, we're writing a simple console app using Visual Studio community, where we build CRUD methods to manage a list of people with firstname, lastname, and a bool.  These also need unique id numbers that can be used later!  Meaning the IDs should be short and manageable.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?  Even a key word would help, as I would at least know  what to look for!  GUIDs and other ways I've seen have been too long.

PS: This is my first application.  Please and thank you!  In the meantime, will continue to dig...

Comment: Usually your database deals with this

Comment: Please tell us how do you connect to the db? Do you use Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Usually your database deals with unique ids. I would suggest using one. However, if you can't use an appropriate fully featured Datestore, and this is only for trivial purposes, a simple novel thread safe approach might be to use a field `static` and `Interlocked.Increment`

**Given**

```
public class Person
{
   // static plumbing
   private static int _current = 0;
   private static int NextId => Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);

   // instance plumbing
   public int Id { get; set; } = NextId;
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var people = new List<Person>();

people.Add(new Person(){ Name ="bob"});
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "glerb" });
people.Add(new Person() { Name = "yeet" });

foreach (var person in people)
   Console.WriteLine($"Id : {person.Id}, Name {person.Name}");
```

**Output**

```
Id : 1, Name bob
Id : 2, Name glerb
Id : 3, Name yeet
```

Basically every time you instantiate a new class you are assured a unique ID.

Note, this will not fill gaps, if you instantiate a class and delete it, the next id won't care and will get the next logical id anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It seems like this works perfectly for this.  
So  just to confirm, I add the top lines of code (under Given) to my POCO? 

What I have now is: 
public class Developer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool HasPluralSight { get; set; }

        public Developer() { }  //Overloading
        public Developer(string firstName, string lastName, bool hasPluralSight)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
            HasPluralSight = hasPluralSight;

Comment: @JoshuaCarr yeah add the top static lines and the ID

Comment: Sorry, that came out really silly within a comment.  So I added the property "public int Id..." to my POCO. Not sure how to make the "=NextID" part to work just yet.  Is the NextID line what tells it to assign the next number in line to that instance of the object?

Comment: @JoshuaCarr yes the  `= NextId;` is run when the object is instantiated and calls the static method, this is what gives you the new id

Comment: One other question and I should be good:

In our app, instructor had us use a seedlist method so that the content wouldn't clear every time the app is exited, inside the method is "Developer joshua = new Developer("Joshua", "Wright", true, int ); -------  Developer jane = new Developer("Jane", "Sweet", false);" etc.  Is there something I can plug in as a fourth parameter (int Idnumber) so the program will plug in each one's unique ID?  Or should I plug the first few in manually?

Comment: @JoshuaCarr if i understand what you are asking, the ID will get created anyway. Ie your constructor could look like this `public Developer(string firstName, string lastName, bool hasPluralSight)` no need to set the ID its always taken care of.. However if you need to set it you can? do you need to set it?

Comment: Users need to be able to use that ID number to add the corresponding user to a list.  Does that make more sense?

Edit:  Managers need to be able to use the ID number to add the corresponding user to a list

Comment: Orrrr I suppose instead of seeding the list manually like I did, can I do something like "private void SeedDevList()  {  ::insert list of developers::  }

Comment: Maybe:

SeedDevList() {  _DeveloperDirectory   }  ?

Comment: "private static int _current = 0;
        private static int NextId => Interlocked.Increment(ref _current);"
Should this be in my CREATE method in the repo?  Or the POCO?

(I really appreciate the help, a lot!)

Comment: @JoshuaCarr well it depends, each poco could have that, which then allows each poco type get their own ids, i would say yes. but its hard to say, there is a case for moving this too the repo, especially if you have a create method. for now i think its succinct in the poco